# Uncaught TypeError: this._addClass is not a function in Product add/edit page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, php-7.0

After updating to 1.7.6.1 Prestashop version, the page for adding and editing products stopped working.

If I comment line number 46 in classes/Media.php, where the slider connection is located:

```
'ui.slider' => array('fileName' => 'jquery.ui.slider.min.js', 'dependencies' => array('ui.core', 'ui.widget', 'ui.mouse'), 'theme' => true),
```

the form starts working fine. But many others cease to function.
The same effect is obtained if we separately exclude the ui.widget or ui.mouse on this line.

Disabling all third-party modules in the settings does not help.

Just open the page for adding or editing products and the following error appears in the browser console:

```
main.bundle.js:221 Uncaught TypeError: this._addClass is not a function
    at e.<computed>.<computed>._create (main.bundle.js:221)
    at e.<computed>.<computed>._create (jquery.ui.widget.min.js:4)
    at e.<computed>.<computed>._createWidget (jquery.ui.widget.min.js:4)
    at new e.<computed>.<computed> (jquery.ui.widget.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.ui.widget.min.js:4)
    at Function.each (main.bundle.js:253)
    at De.fn.init.each (main.bundle.js:253)
    at De.fn.init.e.fn.<computed> [as sortable] (jquery.ui.widget.min.js:4)
    at r.init (form.js?1.7.6.1:1385)
    at r.value (main.bundle.js:253)
```

PrestaShop version: 1.7.6.1

PHP version: 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6

Comment: it seem as jQuery is not defined, if you are developing a custom module try to add `$this->context->controller->addJquery();` in `hookBackOfficeHeader` function

Comment: Disabling a module does not unhook it from displayBackOfficeHeader hook. try unhooking modules from `displayBackofficeHeader` and `actionAdminControllerSetMedia` to see if that makes a difference

Comment: What are the modules that you are using? Maybe I know a module which might be causing this